# eigenvalues for particular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $x \in  \mathbb{C^n}\setminus \{ \vec{0} \}$ be fixed. Find all the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrices $A_1=xx^*$ and 
  $$A_2\ =\ \left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & x^* \\
x & 0 \\
\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: Are you sure, that $x\in \mathbb{C}$ and not something like $x\in\mathbb{C}^{N}$?

Comment: Something like $\Bbb C^{N\times 1}$ or $\Bbb C^{1\times N}$ to be more precised. It makes all the difference for $A_1$.

Comment: and maybe you could add a definition of your star. I suppose it's the transposed and complex conjugated of $A$...but

Comment: Hint: Note that $A_1v=xx^*v$ is always a multiple of $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply stick to the definition of eigenvector. Let $w=\pmatrix{z\\ v}$ be an eigenvector of $A_2$ corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then $A_2w=\lambda w$ and hence
\begin{align*}
x^\ast v &= \lambda z,\tag{1}\\
zx &= \lambda v.\tag{2}
\end{align*}
There are two possibilities:

1. $\lambda = 0$. It follows that $x^\ast v=z=0$ and $v\neq0,\lambda\neq0$. The equation $x^\ast v=0$ also shows that the eigenspace of $\lambda=0$ is $(n-1)$-dimensional.
2. $\lambda\ne0$. Equation $(2)$ implies that $z\neq0$ and $v\neq0$ and $v$ is a scalar multiple of $x$. Choose $v = x$, then $\lambda=z$ and you can determine $\lambda$ from $(1)$ (there are two solutions).

Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A_1$ can be found in a similar manner.